# Ctrl, Shift and Alt keys stopped working in win 10

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, updates

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys on my laptop — hp probook 6460b laptop running Windows 10 — have stopped working; both the left and right sets of keys. I have searched for solutions to this problem but I cannot find anything that works. What can the problem be and what should I try to fix this?

Comment: I do not usually see keyboard drivers for computers.  Try a USB Keyboard (external). If that works, replace the laptop keyboard.

Comment: yes external keyboard works .. actually just a month ago i replaced the laptop keyboard so looks like thats not keboard problem

Comment: Use the HP Driver Update App to update all other drivers including BIOS. We should see if it is a driver issue. Check your Windows 10 or other OS Accessibility Settings to see if this key combination has been used in Accessibility Features

Comment: i did this already .. but problm isnot solved . they were working well today suddenly they stop working

Comment: You said the eternal keyboard works so there is a decent chance the laptop keyboard has failed a second time.

Comment: but its strange that only these buttons at the same time stop working ...its hard to beleieve that only these same buttons are broken in keyboard and others are working well

Answer (score 0):

This laptop is not new and HP does not provide drivers for Windows 10.

The
[HP drivers for Windows 8.1](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-6460b-notebook-pc/5045594)
can still be useful, but the only related one that is not ancient is the BIOS
from Feb 28, 2018, version F.67 Rev. A. Check if this BIOS is not already installed,
and if not then install it very carefully, reading carefully the installation
instructions.

If this does not help, perhaps the installation of Windows 10 had a problem.
Repair it using the method described in the article
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
Read carefully the description and download the latest full installation ISO to do
the repair.

If nothing helps, then Windows 10 does not support well your laptop keyboard.
An external keyboard will most probably work for you.